# What is causing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm getting the subject error message, however I can't figure out why. I have a fairly complex set of controllers. The subject controllers are as follows:

```
package ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin;

import java.util.Locale;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.Node;
import ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.PiProcessor;
import ws.daley.hollow.service.admin.intf.INodeService;
import ws.daley.hollow.service.admin.intf.IPiProcessorService;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.CustomErrorController;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.AdminSerialSubController;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.ElementParameter;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.MyModelAndView;

@Controller
public class AdminPiProcessorController extends AdminSerialSubController<PiProcessor>
{
    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "piprocessor";
    private static final String[] MEMBER_FIELD_NAMES = new String[] {"node"};

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    @Autowired
    CustomErrorController customErrorController;

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    @Autowired
    private IPiProcessorService service;

    @Autowired
    private INodeService memberService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messages;

    public AdminPiProcessorController() {super(PiProcessor.class);}

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void postConstruct() {super.postInit(getClass(), this.service, this.customErrorController, this.messages);}

    private ElementParameter[] getElementParameters()
    {
        return new ElementParameter[] {new ElementParameter(Node.class, "node", false, this.memberService)};
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ Throwable.class})
    @Override
    public ModelAndView throwable(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable throwable) {return super.throwable(request, throwable);}

    @Override
    public String[] getMemberFieldNames() {return MEMBER_FIELD_NAMES;}

    @GetMapping(value = STUB, params = ENTITY_NAME)
    @Override
    public MyModelAndView adminEditEntityList(Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminEditEntityList(model, locale);}

    @GetMapping(value = STUB, params = { ENTITY_NAME, EDIT })
    public MyModelAndView adminWithEntityId(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminWithEntityId(model, locale, name, getElementParameters());}

    @GetMapping(value = STUB, params = { ENTITY_NAME, NEW })
    public MyModelAndView adminWithEntityNew(Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminWithEntityNew(model, locale, getElementParameters());}

    @PostMapping(value = STUB, params = { ENTITY_NAME, SUBMIT })
    public MyModelAndView adminWithEntitySave(@ModelAttribute(ENTITY_NAME) PiProcessor entity, @RequestParam("action") String action, Model model, Locale locale)
    {
        return super.adminWithEntitySubmit(model, locale, action, entity);
    }
}
```

and

```
package ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.Node;
import ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.NodeFunction;
import ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.PiProcessor;
import ws.daley.hollow.service.admin.intf.INodeFunctionService;
import ws.daley.hollow.service.admin.intf.INodeService;
import ws.daley.hollow.service.admin.intf.IPiProcessorService;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.CustomErrorController;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.AdminNameSubController;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.ElementParameter;
import ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.MyModelAndView;

@Controller
public class AdminNodeController extends AdminNameSubController<Node>
{
    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "node";
    private static final String[] MEMBER_FIELD_NAMES = new String[] { "nodeFunction" };

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    @Autowired
    CustomErrorController customErrorController;

    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    @Autowired
    private INodeService service;

    @Autowired
    private IPiProcessorService piProcessorService;

    @Autowired
    private INodeFunctionService memberService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messages;

    public AdminNodeController() {super(Node.class);}

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    public void postConstruct() {super.postInit(getClass(), this.service, this.customErrorController, this.messages);}

    private ElementParameter[] getElementParameters()
    {
        return new ElementParameter[] {new ElementParameter(NodeFunction.class, "nodeFunction", false, this.memberService)};
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ Throwable.class})
    @Override
    public ModelAndView throwable(HttpServletRequest request, Throwable throwable) {return super.throwable(request, throwable);}

    @Override
    public String[] getMemberFieldNames() {return MEMBER_FIELD_NAMES;}

    @GetMapping(value = STUB, params = ENTITY_NAME)
    @Override
    public MyModelAndView adminEditEntityList(Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminEditEntityList(model, locale);}

    @GetMapping(value = STUB, params = { ENTITY_NAME, EDIT })
    public MyModelAndView adminWithEntityId(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminWithEntityId(model, locale, name, getElementParameters());}

    @GetMapping(value = STUB, params = { ENTITY_NAME, NEW })
    public MyModelAndView adminWithEntityNew(Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminWithEntityNew(model, locale, getElementParameters());}

    @PostMapping(value = STUB, params = { ENTITY_NAME, SUBMIT })
    public MyModelAndView adminWithEntitySave(@ModelAttribute(ENTITY_NAME) Node entity, @RequestParam("action") String action, Model model, Locale locale)
    {
        if ("Delete".equals(action))
        {
            Collection<PiProcessor> piProcessors = this.piProcessorService.queryByNode(entity.getName());
            if (piProcessors != null && piProcessors.size() > 0)
            {
                String names = piProcessors.stream().map(r -> r.getName()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
                MyModelAndView mav = super.adminWithEntityId(model, locale, entity.getName());
                mav.addObject("error", "Cannot delete node function. It is used in the following PiProcessor(s): "+names);
                return mav;
            }
        }
        return super.adminWithEntitySubmit(model, locale, action, entity);
    }
}
```

The parameters are:

```
STUB=/server-admin
EDIT=edit
NEW=new
SUBMIT=submit
```

I have also made a copy of AbstractHandler and placed it in the package org.springframework.web.servlet.handler in my own source tree. I have added the made the following changes to it:

Added

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.class);
```

Added

```
            logger.warn("Url :"+request.getContentType().toString());
            logger.warn("Request: "+request.toString());
            logger.warn("Context Path: "+request.getContextPath().toString());
            logger.warn("Method: "+request.getMethod().toString());
            logger.warn("Query string: "+request.getQueryString().toString());
            logger.warn("Scheme: "+request.getScheme().toString());
            Enumeration<String> e = request.getParameterNames();
            while(e.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String parameterName = e.nextElement();
                String parameter = request.getParameter(parameterName).toString();
                logger.warn("Parameter: "+parameterName+"->"+parameter);
            }
            logger.warn("matches:");
            for(Match match:matches)
                logger.warn("\t"+match.toString());
            logger.warn("bestMatch: "+bestMatch.toString());
            logger.warn("secondBestMatch: "+secondBestMatch.toString());
```

just before the statement:

```
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path '" +
                        request.getRequestURL() + "': {" + m1 + ", " + m2 + "}");
```

The output is:

```
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,170 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Url :application/x-www-form-urlencoded
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,170 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Request: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper@21a71563]
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,170 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Context Path: 
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,171 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Method: POST
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,171 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Query string: lang=en_US&piprocessor&submit
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,171 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Scheme: http
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,171 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Parameter: lang->en_US
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,172 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Parameter: piprocessor->
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,172 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Parameter: submit->
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,172 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Parameter: id->16
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,172 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Parameter: name->000000009ec1f24d
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,173 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Parameter: node->18
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,173 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - Parameter: action->Submit
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,173 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - matches:
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,173 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping -  {[/server-admin],methods=[POST],params=[node && submit]}
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,174 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping -  {[/server-admin],methods=[POST],params=[piprocessor && submit]}
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,174 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - bestMatch: {[/server-admin],methods=[POST],params=[node && submit]}
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:32,174 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping - secondBestMatch: {[/server-admin],methods=[POST],params=[piprocessor && submit]}
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:46,821 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] DEBUG ws.daley.hollow.web.error.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler - ws.daley.hollow.web.error.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler::handleInternal(ex={java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8081/server-admin': {public ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.MyModelAndView ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.AdminNodeController.adminWithEntitySave(ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.Node,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Locale), public ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.MyModelAndView ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.AdminPiProcessorController.adminWithEntitySave(ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.PiProcessor,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Locale)}}, request={ServletWebRequest: uri=/server-admin;client=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;session=110061C48999447505CF1AA326575B98;user=test}
webadmin - 2018-02-20 21:13:46,824 [http-nio-8081-exec-9] ERROR ws.daley.hollow.web.error.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler - 500 Status Code
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:8081/server-admin': {public ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.MyModelAndView ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.AdminNodeController.adminWithEntitySave(ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.Node,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Locale), public ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.abstractcontroller.MyModelAndView ws.daley.hollow.web.controller.admin.AdminPiProcessorController.adminWithEntitySave(ws.daley.hollow.persistence.admin.model.PiProcessor,java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.util.Locale)}
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:394)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:323)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:1)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I forgot to mention that I was using spring-boot 1.5.10.RELEASE and have moved to 2.0.0.RC1 and both have this problem.

Additionally, in another dozen or so modules I have exactly the same constructs. AdminPiProcessorController is the only module that exhibits this behavior. The models, repositories, services and controllers are heavily abstracted to allow exactly this style of code. Unfortunately, it makes it very difficult to build a simple test case.

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve]. Most of this code is irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have same mapping in two controllers

```
 AdminPiProcessorController 
 AdminNodeController
```

Because mapping is global for application you cannot use the same uri for two different controllers.

I hope it will help you.

The controller class AdminPiProcessorController :

```
@GetMapping(value = STUB, params = ENTITY_NAME)
    @Override
    public MyModelAndView adminEditEntityList(Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminEditEntityList(model, locale);}
```

has the same mapping as in AdminNodeController

```
@GetMapping(value = STUB, params = ENTITY_NAME)
    @Override
    public MyModelAndView adminEditEntityList(Model model, Locale locale) {return super.adminEditEntityList(model, locale);}
```

Please check other methods as well.

Comment: Can you explain how I have the same mapping? The adminWithEntitySave methods have similar source, however, the @PostMapping params contain ENTITY_NAME which in one case is "piprocessor" and in the other is "node". I have a dozen or so controllers which contain this same content and all the others work properly.

Comment: It would appear that the two methods are indeed the same. However ENTITY_NAME is

Comment: It would appear that the two methods are indeed the same. However ENTITY_NAME is a private static final String declared at the top of each module. In AdminPiProcessorController it is declared as "piprocessor" and in AdminNodeController it is declared as "node". This should result in @GetMapping(value = "/server-admin", params = "piprocessor") for one and @GetMapping(value = "/server-admin", params = "node") for the other.

Comment: But the problem is two different methods are pointing to one url. Url cannot be attached with two methods at the same time.

Comment: If you look at the log, you'll see that the two possible matches are: {[/server-admin],methods=[POST],params=[piprocessor && submit]}
 and {[/server-admin],methods=[POST],params=[node && submit]} and there is a request parameter of "piprocessor" and there is NOT a parameter of "node". I don't see how how a request with a parameter of "piprocessor" can match a parameter of "node".

Comment: I am not talking about parameters. Please have a look on uri definition.

Answer (score 0):

Although not technically an answer, the problem has just gone away on its own. I think a similar problem acted the same way before...